# PHPUnit Code Coverage not working and always saying incorrect whitelist config

Tags: symfony, phpunit, code-coverage

Ich checked on several sources on the network and also here on stack overflow but couldn't solve it so far.

Heres my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.0/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="../../src/test.bootstrap.php"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnError="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     stopOnIncomplete="false"
     stopOnSkipped="false"
     stopOnRisky="false"
     verbose="true"
>
<!--printerFile="vendor/whatthejeff/emoji-phpunit-resultprinter/src/Emoji/PHPUnit/ResultPrinter.php"-->
<!--printerClass="Emoji\PHPUnit\ResultPrinter"-->
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="src/" />
    <env name="BOOTSTRAP_CLEAR_CACHE_ENV" value="testing"/>
</php>

<loggin>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage"/>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
    <log type="coverage-crap4j" target="build/logs/crap4j.xml"/>
    <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
</loggin>

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory>../src</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            <directory>src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
            <directory>src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
</phpunit>
```

Due to the Build Server limitations I need to call phpunit with the following command:

```
./build/bin/phpunit.phar -c build/config/phpunit.xml --coverage-clover build/logs/clover.xml --coverage-crap4j build/logs/crap4j.xml --coverage-html build/coverage --coverage-xml build/logs/coverage.xml --log-junit build/logs/junit.xml --testdox-html build/testdox/testdox.html  --testdox-xml build/logs/testdox.xml src/ -v
```

Everything works except code coverage heres the Result Output:

```
    PHPUnit 6.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

    Runtime:       PHP 7.1.5-1+0~20170522123046.25+jessie~1.gbpb8686b with Xdebug 2.6.0-dev
    Configuration: /home/testcase/build-directories/build/config/phpunit.xml
    Error:         Incorrect whitelist config, no code coverage will be generated.

    ..................                                                18 / 18 (100%)

    Time: 945 ms, Memory: 6.00MB

    OK (18 tests, 68 assertions)
```

I'm a little bit irritated as unit tests itself are working.
The Reds Message can be ignored (Hope so) as the Redis server is not yet fully configured.

I'm using oh-unit 6.1.4

Please give me a clue where the error is in my configuration

Comment: php is in Version 7.1.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to change the whitelist deirectory into you phpunit with this:

```
<whitelist>
    <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
    <exclude>
        <directory>./src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
        <directory>./src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>./src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
        <directory>./src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    </exclude>
</whitelist>
```

Comment: I just modified it and tried it again, still same result. Incorrect whitelist config, no code coverage will be generated. I don't get my mistake.

Comment: I inserted it exactly with the config as you posted.

Comment: ok I have updated my answer adding suffix to directory node, try now please @ChrisWest

Comment: I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: I tried to also validate the phpunit.xml file with xmllint

Comment: Found the solution.

Comment: Problem was the path where the src lies.

Comment: I had the config file underneath the build directory and not in the project route. Moved the file and it worked

Comment: Glad to help.you

Answer (score 1):

The directory given in the `filter/whitelist/directory` XML node is relative to the directory that contains the phpunit configuration file.

I think you should use `../../src`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, so I have update the **whitelist directory path** in phpunit.xml

```html
    <whitelist>
      <directory>./web/core/includes</directory>
      <directory>./web/core/lib</directory>
      <!-- Extensions can have their own test directories, so exclude those. -->
      <directory>./web/core/modules</directory>
      <exclude>
        <directory>./web/core/modules/*/src/Tests</directory>
        <directory>./web/core/modules/*/tests</directory>
      </exclude>
      <directory>./web/modules</directory>
      <exclude>
        <directory>./web/modules/*/src/Tests</directory>
        <directory>./web/modules/*/tests</directory>
        <directory>./web/modules/*/*/src/Tests</directory>
        <directory>./web/modules/*/*/tests</directory>
      </exclude>
      <directory>./web/sites</directory>
     </whitelist>
```